# Identification for a bird in the middle of the tree

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

In the central city of Dobrich Bulgaria, I was following a Great spotted woodpecker in a tree and suddenly I found this other bird on the same tree.

[image: SiviaCurruca]
[image: SiviaCurruca]
[image: SiviaCurruca]

The context of the picture is:

- Country: Bulgaria
- City: Dobrich, Center urban area
- Period: mid August (2016)

I think this is a specimen of `Silvia Curruca`, can anybody confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Lesser whitethroat indeed. Grey head with contrasting white throat and brown body, small bill (the similar Orphean warbler has a much bigger bill).

[image]

Comment: Please add additional detail/evidence and reputable citations supporting your claims. The point of answers is to be helpful to others searching for similar questions in the future, which is made possible by evidence/citations. Unsupported responses to [tag:species-identification] questions should be added as comments and not as answers. Thanks.

Comment: There is no citation involved in identifying birds. In Europe this is the best guide amazon.com/Collins-Bird-Guide-Lars-Svensson/dp/0007268149 But a guide is not enough to identify birds, the field experience is essential (I have been birdwatching for 20 years).